# include different headers for cases

Tags: c++-cli

Is it possible to use for `case 1` one header and for `case 2` another?
Because when I use both headers in program I've got `ambiguous symbol` errors.

header 1(winapifunctions.h)

```
 #include <Windows.h>

 void CallWindowProc(String^ windowtitle)
 {
 };
```

header 2(classes.h)

```
 using namespace System;
 using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

 public delegate void Super();
 public ref class Event{}; 
 public ref class MyException:public DivideByZeroException{};
 public interface class IType{};
 public interface class IVal{};
 public ref class Writer abstract{};
 public ref class Check: public Writer,public IType,public IVal
 .....other classes
```

main program

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "classes.h"
#include "winapifunctions.h"
int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
  //read x
  switch(x){ case 1: {CallWindowProc("title");break;} case 2: { Check^ obj = gcnew Check();break;}
};
```

and error - `IServiceProvider:ambiguous symbol`

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: No.

**Long answer**: includes are processed by the pre-processor, during compile time, while your `case` statements are processed during runtime. There's no way to make a compile-time thing to happen during runtime.

What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I've got header file with methods which uses `Windows.h`. Another header file uses `namespace System,namespace System::Collections::Generic` and I wonder why but when I use both headers I've got ambiguous symbol error. But I need both headers in one program.

Comment: Please, update your question adding the actual code, and the errors messages you're seeing. Hopefully someone will be able to tackle it, as I'm off to bed now. Good luck!

Comment: @apt All you have to do is fully-qualify the symbol references. Some of them need to be `::MyFunction` and others need to be `System::Collections::Generic::MyFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this problem using the following code:

```
// 1.cpp
case 1:
    DoCase1();
    break;
case 2:
    DoCase2();
    break;

// 2.cpp
#include <Windows.h>
void DoCase1()
{
    // ...
}

// 3.cpp
#include <AnotherHeader.h>
void DoCase2()
{
    // ...
}
```

If you would post more code and exact error messages, perhaps a better solution can be found.